Streamlit calendar is not being displayed
I am building a chatbot application in Streamlit that integrates with a calendar component. The calendar should be displayed when certain keywords are detected in the chatbot's response. However, I am running into issues where the calendar either doesn't display correctly or disappears immediately.
I have referenced this from github
Issue: The calendar displays for a second and then disappears. Additionally, the importing the events, calendar_options, custom_css and key d doesn't seem to work as expected.
Question: How can I properly integrate and display the calendar component within my Streamlit chatbot application, ensuring it persists and functions correctly?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
import streamlit as st

from streamlit_calendar import calendar
from lib.pages.calendar_component import events, calendar_options, custom_css, key

def toggle_button():
    st.session_state['button_clicked'] = not st.session_state['button_clicked']


def show_intelliBot_page():
    from dotenv import load_dotenv

    load_dotenv()

    from lib.interpreter.LLMInterpreter import LLMInterpreter
    from langchain_community.callbacks.streamlit import StreamlitCallbackHandler

    from streamlit_calendar import calendar

    if "messages" not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state.messages = []

    for message in st.session_state.messages:
        with st.chat_message(message["role"]):
            st.markdown(message["content"])

    if prompt := st.chat_input("How may I help you?"):
        # st.session_state.messages.append({"role": "user", "content": prompt})
        # Display user message in chat message container
        with st.chat_message("user"):
            st.markdown(prompt)
        # Add user message to chat history
        st.session_state.messages.append({"role": "user", "content": prompt})

        with (st.chat_message("assistant")):
            with st.spinner("Processing..."):
                st_callback = StreamlitCallbackHandler(st.container())
                interpreter = LLMInterpreter(prompt)
                response = interpreter.interpret(prompt, [st_callback])
                st.markdown(response)
                # Add assistant message to chat history
                st.session_state.messages.append({"role": "assistant", "content": response})
                if "edd" in response.lower() or "sourcing" in response.lower():
                    events = [
                        {
                            "title": "Event 1",
                            "color": "#FF6C6C",
                            "start": "2023-07-03",
                            "end": "2023-07-05",
                            "resourceId": "a",
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Event 2",
                            "color": "#FFBD45",
                            "start": "2023-07-01",
                            "end": "2023-07-10",
                            "resourceId": "b",
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Event 3",
                            "color": "#FF4B4B",
                            "start": "2023-07-20",
                            "end": "2023-07-20",
                            "resourceId": "c",
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Event 4",
                            "color": "#FF6C6C",
                            "start": "2023-07-23",
                            "end": "2023-07-25",
                            "resourceId": "d",
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Event 5",
                            "color": "#FFBD45",
                            "start": "2023-07-29",
                            "end": "2023-07-30",
                            "resourceId": "e",
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Event 6",
                            "color": "#FF4B4B",
                            "start": "2023-07-28",
                            "end": "2023-07-20",
                            "resourceId": "f",
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Event 7",
                            "color": "#FF4B4B",
                            "start": "2023-07-01T08:30:00",
                            "end": "2023-07-01T10:30:00",
                            "resourceId": "a",
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Event 8",
                            "color": "#3D9DF3",
                            "start": "2023-07-01T07:30:00",
                            "end": "2023-07-01T10:30:00",
                            "resourceId": "b",
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Event 9",
                            "color": "#3DD56D",
                            "start": "2023-07-02T10:40:00",
                            "end": "2023-07-02T12:30:00",
                            "resourceId": "c",
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Event 10",
                            "color": "#FF4B4B",
                            "start": "2023-07-15T08:30:00",
                            "end": "2023-07-15T10:30:00",
                            "resourceId": "d",
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Event 11",
                            "color": "#3DD56D",
                            "start": "2023-07-15T07:30:00",
                            "end": "2023-07-15T10:30:00",
                            "resourceId": "e",
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Event 12",
                            "color": "#3D9DF3",
                            "start": "2023-07-21T10:40:00",
                            "end": "2023-07-21T12:30:00",
                            "resourceId": "f",
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Event 13",
                            "color": "#FF4B4B",
                            "start": "2023-07-17T08:30:00",
                            "end": "2023-07-17T10:30:00",
                            "resourceId": "a",
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Event 14",
                            "color": "#3D9DF3",
                            "start": "2023-07-17T09:30:00",
                            "end": "2023-07-17T11:30:00",
                            "resourceId": "b",
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Event 15",
                            "color": "#3DD56D",
                            "start": "2023-07-17T10:30:00",
                            "end": "2023-07-17T12:30:00",
                            "resourceId": "c",
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Event 16",
                            "color": "#FF6C6C",
                            "start": "2023-07-17T13:30:00",
                            "end": "2023-07-17T14:30:00",
                            "resourceId": "d",
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Event 17",
                            "color": "#FFBD45",
                            "start": "2023-07-17T15:30:00",
                            "end": "2023-07-17T16:30:00",
                            "resourceId": "e",
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Event 18",
                            "color": "#3D9DF3",
                            "duration": "00:40",
                            "resourceId": "a",
                            "rrule": {
                                "freq": 'weekly',
                                "byweekday": ['tu', 'we'],
                                "interval": 1,
                                "dtstart": '2023-07-04T10:00:00',  # will also accept '20120201T103000'
                                "until": '2023-07-20'  # will also accept '20120201'
                            }
                        },
                    ]
                    calendar_options = {
                        "editable": "true",
                        "navLinks": "true",
                        "selectable": "true",
                        "initialView": "multiMonthYear"
                    }
                    custom_css = """
                                .fc-event-past {
                                    opacity: 0.8;
                                }
                                .fc-event-time {
                                    font-style: italic;
                                }
                                .fc-event-title {
                                    font-weight: 700;
                                }
                                .fc-toolbar-title {
                                    font-size: 2rem;
                                }
                            """
                    key = "multimonth"
                    calendar_state = calendar(events=st.session_state.get("events", events), options=calendar_options,
                                              custom_css=custom_css, key=key)
                    st.session_state.messages.append({"role": "assistant", "content": calendar_state})


I hope this helps... I was going through a similar problem, though my code is much simpler.It seems that calendar view has a quite demanding rendering engine.. try to follow these steps:

do not render the calendar from within any context, yours is within 2 (i.e.: with st.spinning);
If that still doesn't work you might have to instantiate the calendar object outside of the function too;
depending on how you call show_intelliBot_page() from within the streamlit page you will have to change it too: again , do not run it using contexts and if it depends on something like your toggle_button it won't be permanent because that button changes state after its toggled.
try adding st.write(calendar) after the whole thing
last but not least: I had to repeat st.write(f"") three times after each callback update on the calendar! turns out that is absolutely necessary to re-render the calendar after any change - don't ask me how I found that.. no idea.Spent one friday afternoon and an entire saturday to find this one almost by chance.

Good Luck, tell me how it goes!
